# Where is the uninitialized value in this function?

Tags: c, memory, stack, valgrind

I am running a debug-version of my C binary within `valgrind`, which returns numerous errors of the sort `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)`.

Using the symbol table, `valgrind` tells me where to look in my program for this issue:

```
==23899== 11 errors in context 72 of 72:                                                                                                                                                                                                     
==23899== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)                                                                                                                                                                         
==23899==    at 0x438BB0: _int_free (in /foo/bar/baz)                                                                                                                         
==23899==    by 0x43CF75: free (in /foo/bar/baz)                                                                                                                              
==23899==    by 0x4179E1: json_tokener_parse_ex (json_tokener.c:593)                                                                                                                                                                         
==23899==    by 0x418DC8: json_tokener_parse (json_tokener.c:108)                                                                                                                                                                            
==23899==    by 0x40122D: readJSONMetadataHeader (metadataHelpers.h:345)                                                                                                                                                               
==23899==    by 0x4019CB: main (baz.c:90)
```

I have the following function `readJSONMetadataHeader(...)` that calls `json_tokener_parse()`:

```
int readJSONMetadataHeader(...) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    char buffer[METADATA_MAX_SIZE];
    json_object *metadataJSON;
    int charCnt = 0; 
    ...
    /* fill up the `buffer` variable here; basically a */
    /* stream of characters representing JSON data...  */
    ...
    /* terminate `buffer` */
    buffer[charCnt - 1] = '\0';
    ...
    metadataJSON = json_tokener_parse(buffer);
    ...
}
```

The function `json_tokener_parse()` in turn is as follows:

```
struct json_object* json_tokener_parse(const char *str)                                                                                                                                                                                      
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    struct json_tokener* tok;                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    struct json_object* obj;                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

    tok = json_tokener_new();                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    obj = json_tokener_parse_ex(tok, str, -1);                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    if(tok->err != json_tokener_success)                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        obj = (struct json_object*)error_ptr(-tok->err);                                                                                                                                                                                         
    json_tokener_free(tok);                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    return obj;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
}
```

Following the trace back to `readJSONMetadataHeader()`, it seems like the uninitialized value is the `char []` (or `const char *`) variable `buffer` that is fed to `json_tokener_parse()`, which in turn is fed to  `json_tokener_parse_ex()`.

But the `buffer` variable gets filled with data and then terminated before the `json_tokener_parse()` function is called.

So why is `valgrind` saying this value is uninitialized? What am I missing?

Comment: If your code & comments are anything to go by, `charCnt` is uninitialized when it's used.

Comment: Or maybe `buffer` is unitialized, just NUL-terminated.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. When `buffer` gets populated with `char` values, the `charCnt` value is incremented. And I am copying and pasting only relevant variables. I forget to write that it is initialized to `0`, which is now fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It looks from the valgrind error report as if your application is statically linked (in particular, `free` appears to be in the main executable, and not `libc.so.6`).

Valgrind will report bogus errors for statically linked applications.

More precisely, there are intentional "don't care" errors inside libc. When you link the application dynamically, such errors are suppressed by default (via suppressions file that ships with Valgrind).

But when you link your application statically, Valgrind has no clue that the faulty code come from libc.a, and so it reports them.

Generally, statically linking applications on Linux is a bad idea (TM).

Running such application under Valgrind: doubly so: Valgrind will not be able to intercept `malloc/free` calls, and will effectively catch *only* uninitialized memory reads, and *not* heap buffer overflows (or other heap corruption bugs) that it is usually good at.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see `charCnt` initialized.

To see if it comes from `buffer`, simply initialize it with `= {0}`, this also would make your null termination of the buffer obsolete.

Comment: I did try adding `{0}` to the `buffer`, but I continue to get the same error, and in the same functions and same lines.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in `json_tokener_parse_ex()` which you don't show. It's likely it's trying to free something that's not initialized.

Answer (score 1):

```
 buffer[charCnt - 1] = '\0';
```

This will *at least* fail if charCnt happens to be zero.

Comment: Thanks. I have already eliminated this as a potential cause, as an empty `buffer` will result in no metadata and the app will exit early with an error condition (code not shown for clarity).